# Pipe all incoming mail to a command (exim4)

Tags: php, debian, email-server, exim, debian-squeeze

How can I setup Exim to pipe all incoming mail to a command (PHP)? and never reject an email?

I'm using Debain squeeze, and Exim4

Comment: possible duplicate of [forward all mail on a specified domain to script](http://serverfault.com/questions/229964/forward-all-mail-on-a-specified-domain-to-script)

Comment: @mailq except I want all domains, and I use Exim, not Postfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using this config:

```
primary_hostname = mywebsite.com
domainlist local_domains = localhost:mywebsite.com
domainlist relay_to_domains =
hostlist   relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1

received_header_text = Received: by $primary_hostname id $message_exim_id

acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt

never_users = root

host_lookup = *

begin acl

acl_check_rcpt:
  accept domains = mywebsite.com
  accept authenticated = *

begin routers

receive_router:
  debug_print = "R: receive_router for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = mywebsite.com
  transport = php_receive
  no_more

send_router:
  debug_print = "R: send_router for $local_part@$domain"
  unseen = true
  driver = accept
  transport = php_send

dnslookup:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
  no_more

begin transports

remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  return_path = mailer@mywebsite.com

php_receive:
  driver = pipe
  command = /var/mailer/receive >> /var/mailer/receive_output.log
  group = mail

php_send:
  driver = pipe
  command = /var/mailer/send >> /var/mailer/send_output.log
  group = mail

begin rewrite

root@mywebsite.com              mailer@mywebsite.com    Ffrsbc
```

Answer (score 0):

With a permissive ACL and a [pipe transport](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch29.html) Do you really mean *all* incoming mail?

If you want to just write a damn configuration file yourself instead of fighting the Debian way of doing Exim, name it /etc/exim4/exim4.conf - it will override the Debian-specific scattered-in-subdirectories configuration.